# Equality of expressions with different variable names

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-manipulation

I have some multivariate systems of expressions that I want to check for equality up to allowing relabelling of the variables. For example the two expressions below would be the same:

```
ex1={x*y*z, x*y/v, v, y, y/v}
ex2={a*b*z, z*b/u, u, b, b/u}
```

Ideally I also want to allow for setting a variable to 0 as well:

```
ex1={x*y*z, x*y/v, v, y, y/v, p}
ex2={a*b*z, z*b/u, u, b, b/u, 0}
```

But these two would not be equal

```
ex1={x*y*z, x*y/v, v, y, y/v, p,0}
ex2={a*b*z, z*b/u, u, b, b/u, 0,q}
```

How can I recognize this kind of equality up to variable relabeling and zeroing?

Comment: This is the textbook use of `Function` if I understood what you mean. For example: `ex1={#1*#2*#3, #1*#2/#4, #4, #2, #2/#4}&`

Comment: How do I then check for equality of that kind of expression? For example: ```ex1 = {#1*#2*#3, #1*#2/#4, #4, #2, #2/#4} &;
ex2 = {#4*#3*#2, #4*#3/#1, #1, #3, #3/#1} &;
SameQ[ex1, ex2] (*False*)``` But I want this to evaluate True

Comment: Simply define a function as `ex={#1*#2*#3, #1*#2/#4, #4, #2, #2/#4, #5}&` and check if `ex1==ex@@{x,y,z,v,p} && ex2==ex@@{a,b,z,u,0}`

Comment: Those evaluate as false for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very naive approach by generating all possible relabelings. Function `findIsomorphism` returns one of the possible relabelings or `False` if none is found.

```
getSymbols[m_] := DeleteDuplicates@Cases[m, _Symbol, Infinity];

findIsomorphism[ex1_, ex2_] := Module[{sym1, sym2, perms, eq},
  sym1 = getSymbols[ex1];
  sym2 = getSymbols[ex2];
  
  If[Length@sym1 != Length@sym2, Return[False]];
  
  perms = MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {sym1, #}] & /@ Permutations[sym2];
  
  eq = ((ex1 /. #) === ex2) & /@ perms;
  
  If[NoneTrue[eq, TrueQ], False, First@perms[[FirstPosition[eq, True]]]]
]

findIsomorphism[{x, y}, {a, b}]
(* {x -> a, y -> b} *)

findIsomorphism[{x + y, z}, {a - b, c}]
(* False *)

findIsomorphism[{x*y*z, x*y/v, v, y, y/v}, {a*b*z, z*b/u, u, b, b/u}]
(* {x -> z, y -> b, z -> a, v -> u} *)
```

To allow for the variables being 0, we can include 0 as a "dummy" variable.

```
findIsomorphismAllowZero[ex1_, ex2_] := 
 Module[{sym1, sym2, perms, eq, exx1, exx2},
  sym1 = getSymbols[ex1];
  sym2 = getSymbols[ex2];
  
  If[Length@sym1 < Length@sym2,
   {sym1, sym2} = {sym2, sym1}; {exx1, exx2} = {ex2, ex1},
   {exx1, exx2} = {ex1, ex2}
   ];
  
  perms = 
   MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {sym1, #}] & /@ 
    Permutations[
     sym2~Join~ConstantArray[0, Length@sym1], {Length@sym1}];
  
  eq = ((exx1 /. #) === exx2) & /@ perms;
  
  If[NoneTrue[eq, TrueQ], False, First@perms[[FirstPosition[eq, True]]]]
]

findIsomorphismAllowZero[{x, y}, {a, 0}]
(* {x -> a, y -> 0} *)

findIsomorphismAllowZero[{0, x}, {a, b}]
(* {a -> 0, b -> x} *)

findIsomorphismAllowZero[{x, y}, {a + b, c}]
(* {a -> x, b -> 0, c -> y} *)

Quiet@findIsomorphismAllowZero[{x*y*z, x*y/v, v, y, y/v, p}, {a*b*z, 
   z*b/u, u, b, b/u, 0}]
(* {x -> z, y -> b, z -> a, v -> u, p -> 0} *)
```

Comment: This is probably too computationally intensive for my purposes as I am going to repeat this many times

Comment: Have you tried it and measure the timing? It takes 30 ms for the last case on my laptop. What is the performance goal you want to reach?

Comment: I just did some testing and it's more efficient than I thought it would be

Comment: This does work however when the number of variables grows the number permutations grows too fast for this to be practical in my case (~20 variables in each expression)

Comment: @David, you are absolutely right. You had four variables in your initial question, so I did not think you needed a solution for up to 20 (or even more?). I guess the code could be optimized to generate permutations on each of the term in a list separately. This would help if not all 20 of them appear in the same element.

Comment: I think I can make something like that work, thanks!

Comment: You could probably cut down the search space significantly with some tricks. For example, you could check which symbols appear with which `Power`s to narrow down what symbol can possibly correspond to what.

Answer (score 1):

We can `Replace` the leaves of an expression with `Pattern`s and use the resulting patterns with `MatchQ`:

```
ClearAll[exprToPattern, isomorphicExpressionsQ]

exprToPattern = Replace[
       Replace[#, $s_Symbol :> pattern[$s, Blank[]], {-1}],
    {p : pattern[_, Blank[]] :> (p | _?NumericQ), 
     p_?NumericQ :> (p | _)}, 1] /. pattern -> Pattern &;

isomorphicExpressionsQ = MatchQ[exprToPattern@#] @ #2 && MatchQ[exprToPattern@#2] @ #1 &;
```

***Examples:***

```
exa1 = {x*y*z, x*y/v, v, y, y/v}
exa2 = {a*b*z, z*b/u, u, b, b/u}

isomorphicExpressionsQ[exa1, exa2]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
exb1 = {x*y*z, x*y/v, v, y, y/v, p}
exb2 = {a*b*z, z*b/u, u, b, b/u, 0}
exb3 = {a*b*z, z*b/u, u, b, b/u, q + 3}

isomorphicExpressionsQ @@@ Subsets[{exb1, exb2, exb3}, {2}]
```

> ```
> {True, False, False}
> ```

```
exc1 = {x*y*z, x*y/v, v, y, y/v, p, 0}
exc2 = {a*b*z, z*b/u, u, b, b/u, 0, q}
exc3 = {a*b*z, z*b/u, u, b, b/u, 0, q + 3}

isomorphicExpressionsQ @@@ Subsets[{exc1, exc2, exc3}, {2}]
```

> ```
> {True, False, False}
> ```